# No route matches [POST] "/users/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I was trying to create a update form for the registered users in my applcation

View:

```
<h2><%= @title =%></h2>

<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error">
<h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count,"error") %> prohibited this user from registering</h2>
<ul>
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg%></li>
<%end%>
</ul>
</div>
<%end%>

<%= form_for :user do |form| %>

<div class="reg_form">
<label for="first_name">First Name: </label>
<%= form.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="reg_form">  
<label for = "last_name">Last Name: </label>
<%= form.text_field  :last_name %>
</div>
<div class="reg_form">
<%=form.submit "Update"%>
</div> 
<%end%>
```

Controller: users_controller.rb

```
def index
    unless session[:user_id]
        flash[:notice] = "Please Login first"
        redirect_to :action => "new"
    end
    @title = "Profile"
    @user=User.find(session[:user_id])
end


def edit
    @title="Profile Update"
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    if param_posted?(:user)
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
            redirect_to :controller => "user", :action => "profile"
        end
    end
end
```

I included  get "edit"=> 'users#edit' in routes.rb. However, I get an error 
    'No route matches [POST] "/users/edit"'

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: instead of using this <%= form_for :user do |form| %>, try to replace with  <%= form_for @user do |form| %>

Comment: @Lalitharyani So no other changes for controller?

Comment: there is no need to define routes for edit explicit in your routes file...simply add resources :users and it will make default routes for your edit action

Comment: @Lalitharyani resources :users is already included in the routes.rb and changing to '@user' did not help. Any other suggestion?

Comment: try to run rake routes from your console and remove the routes for edit that you have define explicit.

Comment: Returns the following: 

    users POST   /users(.:format)         users#create ||

    new_users GET    /users/new(.:format)     users#new ||

    edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format)    users#edit ||

              GET    /users(.:format)         users#show ||
              PATCH  /users(.:format)         users#update ||
              PUT    /users(.:format)         users#update ||
              DELETE /users(.:format)         users#destroy ||

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RESTful `edit` route should use a GET verb. The vanilla `resource#edit` method doesn't change the database, but simply puts up a form populated with the selected resource's values. Submitting that form to `resource#update` (using the PUT verb) does the work of actually changing the database.

So, your `users#edit` method isn't doing what a standard RESTful edit action does. I'd suggest using the Standard Way unless you have a really good reason and you document that reason carefully. I concur that spending time looking at rails routing guides and a vanilla controller would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `POST` route to handle the form submission. Try `resources :users` in routes.rb and do a `rake routes` in command prompt to see all your available routes.

I recommend you review the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) and look at all the methods created using `scaffold` and how Rails handles the routing for different things to each of the methods.